# How to run tasks concurrently from a list in asyncio? (Python 3.7 and above)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In official docs of asyncio:

```
import asyncio

async def factorial(name, number):
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, number + 1):
        print(f"Task {name}: Compute factorial({i})...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        f *= i
    print(f"Task {name}: factorial({number}) = {f}")

async def main():
    # Schedule three calls *concurrently*:
    await asyncio.gather(
        factorial("A", 2),
        factorial("B", 3),
        factorial("C", 4),
    )

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
 Expected output:

 Task A: Compute factorial(2)...
 Task B: Compute factorial(2)...
 Task C: Compute factorial(2)...
 Task A: factorial(2) = 2
 Task B: Compute factorial(3)...
 Task C: Compute factorial(3)...
 Task B: factorial(3) = 6
 Task C: Compute factorial(4)...
 Task C: factorial(4) = 24
```

Assume that, we further simplify this function *factorial* by removing the parameter **name**

```
async def factorial(number):
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, number + 1):
        print(f"Task {number}: Compute factorial({i})...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        f *= i
    print(f"Task {number}: factorial({number}) = {f}")
```

and say, I have a huge list of numbers to call this *factorial* function, so it's not feasible/realistic for me to write down every call of this function inside the `asyncio.gather()`

```
    await asyncio.gather(
        factorial(2),
        factorial(3),
        factorial(4),
        factorial(5),
        ...
        ...
        ...
        factorial(N),
    )
```

For trial purposes, my attempt was this:

```
async def main():

    numList = [2,3,4]
    
    await asyncio.gather(
        factorial(num) for num in numList
    )

asyncio.run(main())
```

Unfortunately getting the error of:

```
    RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'factorial' was never awaited
    RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <coroutine object factorial at 0x102c95b00>
```

TL;DR

**How can I concurrently run tasks in asyncio from a list?**

P.S. I will favor the solutions with new asyncio methods like `run`, `create_task`; and will follow the discouragement of the official documents about `event_loop`

Answer (score 1):

To run corutines from a **list**, you need to **unpack** these into `gather`, because according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) `gather` uses packing for it `aws` argument

```
    await asyncio.gather(*[factorial(num) for num in numList])
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.